# I don't understand closure of my question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question

[Trouble iterating over an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071384/trouble-iterating-over-an-object)

was closed for either a typo (which I don't see) or because it's not reproducible, which it is. Can I get a little more clarification?

Answer (score 14):

It is obvious why the first person voted to close. They also left a comment:

> Your `begin` and `end` return a copy of the object (`data_vector`) instead of a reference (`data_vector&`).

You replied with:

> Makes no difference, but I edited the code anyway

but the first vote had already been cast. So had a second vote for the same reason. (You only get one chance to make a first impression. Best to check and make sure that these sort of typos don't sneak in, *even if they don't actually matter*.)

What I do not know is why the 3rd close vote got cast, over 15 minutes after you confirmed that was not the problem and updated the question. I guess they missed the fact that you edited to clarify the *suspected* problem was not the only problem.

Either way, I've re-opened it now. There's nothing wrong with the question, now that you've addressed the suspected typo. I have also deleted the obsolete comments, which were all referring to an older version of the question and may therefore be confusing to future readers.

Comment: I know that the person making that comment has a lot of reputation, but that *was* *no* *typo*. (As evinced by the fact that indulging them didn't fix anything.) More like common practice. Can you tell them not to shoot from the hip like that?

Comment: You want me to tell someone not to be wrong? I'm not sure how successful that will be.

Comment: Not close a question, especially not without giving a reason, immediately once you see anything marginally off. But never mind. I'll let this go.

Comment: The person who voted to close it *did* give a reason. They thought they'd found a typo in your code that was causing the problem.  Yes, it happened that their assessment of your code was wrong, but that doesn't mean they did anything wrong. **It is normal and encouraged to close questions when you think the problem is caused by a typo that would make the answers not useful to others in the future.** (Remember that Stack Overflow is not a help desk; rather, we are building a library of answers to programming questions. Helping the person who asked the question is just a side benefit.)